# Count occurrence of word in ArrayList of String

Tags: java, arraylist

I have large ArrayList of Strings. Each String element of the list is quite large too. I want to count how many times the word "the" appears in each element of the list. My current code only iterates through index 1. How do I make it count for all elements of the array?

```
public static int counter(List<String> comments) {
    for (String comment : comments.subList(1, comments.size() - 1)) {

        String a[] = comment.split(" ");

        String word = "the";
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {

            if (word.equals(a[j])) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(comment);
        return count;
    }
    System.out.println("sefsfsfseesfeseeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you want separate counts for each element, or a total count across the whole list? The main problem so far seems to be the return inside the for loop, you stop the method immediately after the first element.

Comment: I wish to get total count across whole list. Index 0 is null, which is why I use sub list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count occurrences of words in ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211194/count-occurrences-of-words-in-arraylist)

Comment: I suggest that you read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for some tips to debug your own code. You have made a small error and these tips should help you find it.

Comment: See how to skip first index in for loop https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22112212/how-to-skip-the-first-iteration-in-a-for-each-loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not call `subList` and return after iterate the whole list:

```
public static int counter(List<String> comments) {
    int count = 0;
    String word = "the";
    for (String comment : comments) {
        String a[] = comment.split(" ");
        for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
            if (word.equals(a[j])) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(comment);
    }
    System.out.println("sefsfsfseesfeseeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee");
    return count;
}
```

Comment: This is a step in the right direction. However, when I use a for each loop to print out each comment in the list, I copy and pasted the output into word and searched for "the" and it amounts to 423. The counter method only shows 248. Whats going on here?

Comment: @dinosaurjohnson I updated the answer.  Maybe there are some words like  `they`, you can search it. But it will not be counted.

Comment: You may have to convert both strings to lower by testing just the and not The this may be missing out ‘The’ , ‘THe’

Comment: aw man, microsoft word is obviously counting "the" that appears in "their" etc, foolish mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The type of your method is not correct instead it should be `Map<String, Long>`
If you are using Java 8 you can create a map of each word and its frequency like this :

```
Map<String, Long> result = comments.stream()
    .flatMap(comment -> Stream.of(comment.split("\\s+")))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

Then if you want how much `the` appears you can use :

```
String word = "the";
Long count = result.get(word);
```

Or Just :

```
Long count = comments.stream()
        .flatMap(comment -> Stream.of(comment.split("\\s+")))
        .filter(s -> s.equals(word))
        .count();
```